# Issue with Connecting IBM MQ Using Externalized User Credential - Spring Boot + JMS + IBM MQ 8.0.0.9

Tags: spring-boot, jms, ibm-mq, spring-jms

I need a help for the captioned subject. Request your suggestion here.

I am using spring boot framework to get the messages from IBM MQ 8.0.0.9. The attached program meets the basic expectation. However, It always uses the OS credential (in specifically Windows Login credential) to connect to the IBM MQ. But I would like it to use the credential this is given in property file. Even if, I intentionally give wrong credential in the property files, the program happily connects with the IBM MQ (using windows login credential which has access to the IBM MQ as well).

Here is the MQ Details - 
MQ Version 8.0.0.9, 
QM Version 8.0.0.9, 
CONNAUTH - Not Set, 
CHLAUTH - Disabled, 
QMGR CONNAUTH - Not Set, 
CHCKCLNT - OPTIONAL, 
AUTHINFO - SYS.DEFAULT.AUTHINFO.IDPWOS

Could you suggest what I am doing wrong here in the attach program. I have tried the commented line of code as well.

```
@EnableJms
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class JmsConfig {
    @Value("${ibm.mq.host}")
    private String host;
    @Value("${ibm.mq.port}")
    private Integer port;
    @Value("${ibm.mq.queueManager}")
    private String queueManager;
    @Value("${ibm.mq.channel}")
    private String channel;
    @Value("${ibm.mq.responseQueue}")
    private String responseQueue;
    @Value("${ibm.mq.userName}")
    private String userName;
    @Value("${ibm.mq.password}")
    private String password;
    @Value("${ibm.mq.receiveTimeout}")
    private long timeout;

    @Autowired(required=true)
    @Qualifier(value="responseListener")
    MessageListener  responseListener;

    @Bean (name="queueConnectionFactory")
    public MQQueueConnectionFactory mqQueueConnectionFactory() {
        MQQueueConnectionFactory mqQueueConnectionFactory = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();

        try {
            mqQueueConnectionFactory.setHostName(host);
            mqQueueConnectionFactory.setTransportType(WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
            mqQueueConnectionFactory.setChannel(channel);
            mqQueueConnectionFactory.setPort(port);
            mqQueueConnectionFactory.setQueueManager(queueManager);
            mqQueueConnectionFactory.setCCSID(819);
            /*
            mqQueueConnectionFactory.setBooleanProperty(WMQConstants.USER_AUTHENTICATION_MQCSP, true);
            mqQueueConnectionFactory.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.USERID, userName);
            mqQueueConnectionFactory.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.PASSWORD, password);
            mqQueueConnectionFactory.setStringProperty(CMQC.USER_ID_PROPERTY, userName);
            mqQueueConnectionFactory.setStringProperty(CMQC.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, password);
            */
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            log.error("Error occured: " + e);
        }

        return mqQueueConnectionFactory;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean (name="userCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter")
    @DependsOn(value = { "queueConnectionFactory" })
    UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter getUserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter(
            MQQueueConnectionFactory mqQueueConnectionFactory) {
        UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter userCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter = new UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter();
        userCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter.setUsername(userName);
        userCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter.setPassword(password);
        userCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter.setTargetConnectionFactory(mqQueueConnectionFactory);
        return userCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter;
    }

    @Bean (name="simpleMessageListenerContainer")
    @DependsOn(value = { "userCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter" })
    public SimpleMessageListenerContainer queueResponseContainer(ConnectionFactory userCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter) {
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer simpleMessageListenerContainer = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
        simpleMessageListenerContainer.setConnectionFactory(userCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter);
        simpleMessageListenerContainer.setConnectLazily(true);
        simpleMessageListenerContainer.setDestinationName(responseQueue);
        simpleMessageListenerContainer.setMessageListener(responseListener);
        return simpleMessageListenerContainer;
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsOperations jmsOperations(ConnectionFactory userCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter) {
        JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate(userCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter);
        jmsTemplate.setReceiveTimeout(timeout);
        return jmsTemplate;
    }
}

====================

@Component(value="responseListener")
public class ResponseListener implements MessageListener {

    public void onMessage(Message message) {    
        ...
    }
}

===================

@Component
public class ContainerChecker {

    @Autowired
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer  queueContainer;

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 300000)
    public void reportContainerStatus() throws ServiceException{
        if(!queueContainer.isActive()) {
            ...
        } else {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you also manage the queue manager?  What MQ version is used on the queue manager?  Do you have `CONNAUTH` enabled?  If the MQ queue manager is v7.5 or lower (which would be out of support without extended support) MQ out of the box does not know how to authenticate users, and based on settings like `CHLAUTH` may just take the asserted user which based on your MQ v8 client app would be the user your program runs under.  The same would be true for MQ v8 where `QMGR CONNAUTH` is blank, or if filled in the `AUTHINFO` object has `CHCKCLNT(NONE)` set.

Comment: If your queue manager configuration fits one of the situations above, then from the app side you could set `WMQConstants.USER_AUTHENTICATION_MQCSP` to `FALSE` or leave it unset which defaults to `FALSE`, this  will cause the IBM MQ Classes for JMS to send the user you specify in `WMQConstants.USERID` as the asserted user instead of the user your program runs under.  Please keep in mind that no authentication would be taking place, the password would be ignored by the queue manager, anyone that knows the host/port/channel/user to send could connect.

Comment: If you can provide some more details as per above questions, then I can give some more specific suggestions in a answer.

Comment: @JoshMc Thank You first of all. I do not manage the MQ so I need to get those answer first. I will get back to you (even if it get resolved).
BTW MQ version is 8.x

Comment: Is the queue manager also at 8.0?

Comment: MQ Version 8.0.0.9, QM Version 8.0.0.9, CONNAUTH - Not Set, CHLAUTH - Disabled, QMGR CONNAUTH - Not Set, CHCKCLNT - OPTIONAL, AUTHINFO - SYS.DEFAULT.AUTHINFO.IDPWOS

Comment: Hi @JoshMc Do you see any issue with the above values ?

Comment: As I mentioned above that setup means no authentication would be taking place, the password would be ignored by the queue manager, anyone has network access to your queue manager host and IP and knows the host/port/channel/user to configure could connect to that queue manager.  The only other extra security that could be in place would be a server side security exit that does authentication, the `SVRCONN` channel property `SCYEXIT` could be checked to see if this was true.

Comment: Note the channel could also be configured to require the client to pass a specific cert over TLS, but based on your app configuration that is not the case.

Comment: @JoshMc Looks like things are working now. Per your suggestion, the below changes are done (un-commented the below snippet) additionally I have commented "userCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter" bean -
  
 mqQueueConnectionFactory.setBooleanProperty(WMQConstants.USER_AUTHENTICATION_MQCSP, false);
mqQueueConnectionFactory.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.USERID, userName);
mqQueueConnectionFactory.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.PASSWORD, password);

Please let me know how to close this chain. I am new over here. - Thank You.

Comment: Can you please click edit and update your question with the information you provided on the queue manager config yesterday as well as your update for how you fixed it.  I'll put my info in a answer and you can just click accept (the grayed out check mark).

Comment: @JoshMc I will do - probably by eod today. - Thank You

Comment: Will you be accepting my answer?

Comment: I am cleaning up my question and accepting the answer. got late sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the updates in your comments:

- Your application is using the IBM MQ classes for JMS from IBM MQ v8.0.0.9
- Your application is connecting to a IBM MQ queue manager also running v8.0.0.9.

  - The queue manager has CONNAUTH disabled [`QMGR CONNAUTH('')`]
  - The queue manager has CHLAUTH disabled [`QMGR CHLAUTH(DISABLED)'].

In your configuration you show the following bean:

```
@Bean (name="userCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter")
@DependsOn(value = { "queueConnectionFactory" })
UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter getUserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter(
        MQQueueConnectionFactory mqQueueConnectionFactory) {
    UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter userCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter = new UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter();
    userCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter.setUsername(userName);
    userCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter.setPassword(password);
    userCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter.setTargetConnectionFactory(mqQueueConnectionFactory);
    return userCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter;
}
```

You also have the following commented out code:

```
        /*
        mqQueueConnectionFactory.setBooleanProperty(WMQConstants.USER_AUTHENTICATION_MQCSP, true);
        mqQueueConnectionFactory.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.USERID, userName);
        mqQueueConnectionFactory.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.PASSWORD, password);
        mqQueueConnectionFactory.setStringProperty(CMQC.USER_ID_PROPERTY, userName);
        mqQueueConnectionFactory.setStringProperty(CMQC.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, password);
        */
```

---

With IBM MQ classes for JMS v8.0 and later the default for the setting `WMQConstants.USER_AUTHENTICATION_MQCSP` is `FALSE`.  This denotes that the client should work in compatibility mode, this means the MQ client works as it did in version 7.5 and lower, MQCSP did not exist in those older versions and the username and password specified were sent in some fields called `RemoteUserIdentifier` and `RemotePassword` and were limited to 12 characters.

With MQ v8 and higher the IBM MQ classes for JMS now support a new way to send the username and password, this is the MQCSP struction.  This has some benefits for example it can passwords that are longer than 12 characters.  If `WMQConstants.USER_AUTHENTICATION_MQCSP` is `TRUE` the username and password specified will be sent in the MQCSP structure and the `RemoteUserIdentifier` that is used in compatibility mode is instead filled in with the username the process is running under and the `RemotePassword` field is left blank.

I can't find anything that leads me to believe that the `userCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter` bean does anything with the `WMQConstants.USER_AUTHENTICATION_MQCSP` setting so this would lead me to believe it should be sending the username and password you specified in the fields called `RemoteUserIdentifier` and `RemotePassword`.  If you used the commented out code instead it would send the username and password you specified in the MQCSP and your windows login id that is running the process would be sent in the `RemoteUserIdentifier` field.

---

A queue manager at v8 with the configuration you have specified will completely disregard anything in the MQCSP structure and will only look at the `RemoteUserIdentifier` field.  You also said CHLAUTH is DISABLED, so this means that there are no CHLAUTH rules in place that would restrict or change the username that the client sends.  If the `SVRCONN` channel has a blank MCAUSER, then the userid sent in the `RemoteUserIdentifier` field will be used for queue authorization checks.

I suspect that when you noted your "windows login credential" coming across to the queue manager it was when you had `WMQConstants.USER_AUTHENTICATION_MQCSP` set to `TRUE`.  By setting this to `FALSE` you can specify any ID you want to be sent to MQ and because of the configuration of the queue manager it will accept that ID and use it, the password is not verified.

Since the password is not checked by MQ it does not matter what value if any you specify for the password, the following would be able to connect sending the specified username.

```
mqQueueConnectionFactory.setBooleanProperty(WMQConstants.USER_AUTHENTICATION_MQCSP, FALSE);
mqQueueConnectionFactory.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.USERID, userName);
```

---

### Notes about the queue manager setup

Because CONNAUTH is not configured and CHLAUTH is also DISABLED you can connect to the queue manager and specify the `mqm` id (if the queue manager is on Unix) or the `MUSR_MQADMIN` id (if the queue manager is on Windows) and you would have full MQ authority over all queues on the queue manager.

The current configuration provides no security to prevent anyone that has access connect over the network to the queue manager's host and port from accessing any resources the queue manager has available, in most cases this could also be leveraged to execute anything you want on the server where the queue manager runs.

Comment: Thank You.

The bean "userCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter" has been taken off and related dependency has been resolved with "queueConnectionFactory".

Additionally I have un-commented the commented lines of code (with a change from "true" to "false"). However, the last 2 lines might be redundant.